# Web server for Android

Tags: android, web

I'a currently building an app for android that users connect to it by UserName and Password.

When ever a user connects the server should recognized if he has any unread msg's (msgs are uploaded by the user) if he has an unread msg i want all of the users to see that he has an unread msg by adding an icon near his nickname so everyone will see this icon (it doesnt matter if an icon is added or the nickname is colored in red)

What I need is a good tutorial or some code example i can learn from about such a thing.

Any Help would be great.

Kind Reggards

Comment: [SwiFTP](http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/) could be interesting to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android

connected sample.  The key thing that it does is request the account from the AccountManager API so it's easy to track users.  (it also includes C2DM code that can be used to push messages to the users so that they don't actually have to poll the server to get updates)

AppEngine can then be used to create a database-based system that can be used to manage the message data on the back end.  If you'd rather use another server environment, the connected code is still relevant, but you'll have to modify it for the architecture you choose to use.